# UIButton imageForState is not correct after the app returns from being in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton declared in the .h file as

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnQuarter;
```

When I have

```
if ([self.btnQuarter imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == [UIImage imageNamed:@"match.png"])
```

as soon as the app loads it works perfectly. However when the app returns from being locked or being on the home screen it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
 - (IBAction)nextQtr:(id)sender

   {
    if ([[sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"match.png"]])

   }
```

Comment: Nah, that didn't work either. Could it have something to do with declaring it as (retain, nonatomic) and arc?

Comment: when we click btnQuarter then some action call like touchupinside

Comment: Still no luck. It works as soon as the app opens, but then when I lock the device and unlock it and tap the button it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because you're comparing pointers to objects. In your case they point to different `UIImage`s, even though the images themselves contain the same data. `[UIImage imageNamed:]` caches the image, which is why on app startup it works properly, however when you enter background the cache is released (I think) in order to free memory. When you return from the background to foreground, the [`UIImage imageNamed:]` call creates the same `UIImage`, but at another memory address.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is there an alternative that will work?

Comment: I think you should not compare UIImage's. Probably when you set an the image to the button, set another variable (enum or BOOL) to keep a context of which UIImage have you set to the button, and then compare that primitive variable.